# How to manipulate numeric output with variable-like properties based on user input

Tags: python, output, numeric

I am computing digits of pi based on Ramanujan's formula, and I'm allowing the user to control the number of iterations of the summation. I want the number of decimal places to change based on the desired number of iterations.

Python doesn't allow numeric output to change as far as I know with using:

result = 3.14159...

a = 50

b = 48

`print('result = %a.bf' % result')`

But based on number of iterations the precision of pi sky rockets, but for small number of iterations (1, 2, ...) not many decimal places are needed.

What I would like to happen is the following:

```
while True:

   k = int(input("How many iterations do you want? "))

   num_digits = k * 10
   a = num_digits
   b = num_digits - 2

   result = calculate_pi(k)

   print('result = %a.bf' % result')
   .
   . 
   .
```

I understand that this is not how Python's numeric formatting works but I don't know how to translate what I want to happen in English into the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python3.6+:

```
print(f'result = %{a}.{b}f' % result)
```

older python:

```
print(('result = %%%d.%df' % (a, b)) % result) # %% is used to escape '%'
print('results = %{}.{}f'.format(a, b) % a)
```

In both cases, the idea is to first create a string with the right placeholder you want (`%X.Yf`) and then using it in a second pass.

Comment: Works, thank you!

For future users, replace `a` with `result` to print the final answer.

Comment: oops, didn't pay attention. Fixed !